# Dart 2: Build CSP-compliant JS

Tags: dart

With Dart 1 I was able to specify some dart2js options in the transformers section of my pubspec.yaml, in particular, the option to make the resulting JS CSP-compliant:

```
transformers:
  - $dart2js:
      csp: true
```

How can I get the same thing in builder-land?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this configuration of the build_web_compilers builder to your `build.yaml` file:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        release_options:
          dart2js_args:
            - --csp
```

Other useful options include `-O3` (compiler optimization level), `--minify`.